# JQuery Toggle: Cancel Timer

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a jQuery script that toggles a navigation menu, and then closes it after five seconds:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function toggleMenu() {
      $( "#menu-nav" ).toggle( "blind", 500 );
    };
     $( ".nav-open" ).click(function() {
      toggleMenu();
      setTimeout(function(){
         $( "#menu-nav" ).toggle( "blind", 500 );
     }, 5000);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

It works great.

I also want the menu to close when the user clicks on one of the links:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    function closeMenu() {
      $( "#menu-nav" ).toggle( "blind", 500 );
    };
     $( ".nav-close" ).click(function() {
      closeMenu();
      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
```

It works great, as well.

The problem is that if the when the user clicks on the link, the timer is still running. When it hits the 5 second mark, it toggles, so the menu reappears. Then, if the user clicks on the element that shows the menu, it closes it, but restarts the timer, the menu appears after five seconds, and everything gets out of whack.

How can get the second script to cancel the timer in the first script, or am I just going about all of this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(function() {
    var timer, menuNav = $("#menu-nav");

    function toggleNav(){ menuNav.toggle("blind", 500); }

    $( ".nav-open" ).click(function() {
        toggleNav();
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            toggleNav();
        }, 5000);
    });
    $( ".nav-close" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        toggleNav();
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution works, but I think it has timing problems and it does not make good use of jquery animation queue

Comment: @KhanhTo - I understand your point but I can't see the timing problems you refer to. Personally, I think my answer is a fairly clean and efficient way of solving the OP's problem.

Comment: you would see that if the setTimeout were 500, which means toggle again immediately when the first toggle completes.

Comment: yes, I do agree with you this solution is clean and solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @KhanhTo - of course that would happen. However, the OP would never set it to that value because there wouldn't be any point. They specifically say "closes it after five seconds" which is exactly what the code does.

Comment: in this case, it's lucky that 5000 and 500 are big different and likely never runs into timing problem. But the code is not robust if the times are not big different. Anyways, this is just my opinion (answered below). Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

```
// when setting the timer
var id = setTimeout(...);

// before executing any other task, cancel timer:
clearTimeout(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `toggle()`, use `show()` and `hide()` instead.

Comment: That would certainly make things easier, but the client also wants the menu to close if the user clicks the trigger element, after it's been opened.

Comment: Ok, then maybe you can check if menu element it is visible with $(element).is(":visible")?

If it is visible then hide it, if not - show it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first code block has timing problems. But in your case, it does not show up because the timeout value (5000) is greater than the animation value (500). As I understand, you use setTimeout to toggle again when the animation completes, but a better way to do this is to provide a callback function.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function toggleMenu() {
      $( "#menu-nav" ).toggle( "blind", 500, function(){ 
               setTimeout(function(){
                           $( "#menu-nav" ).toggle( "blind", 500 );
                          }, 4500);
           });
    };
     $( ".nav-open" ).click(function() {
      toggleMenu();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Or even better by putting a delay in the queue

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        function toggleMenu() {
          $( "#menu-nav" ).toggle("blind", 500)
                          .delay(4500)
                          .toggle("blind",500);
        };
         $( ".nav-open" ).click(function() {
          toggleMenu();
        });
      });
 </script>
```

With this approach, your script to closeMenu is as simple as:

```
$(function() {
    function closeMenu() {
      $( "#menu-nav" ).stop(true,true).toggle( "blind", 500 );
    };
     $( ".nav-close" ).click(function() {
      closeMenu();
      return false;
    });
  });
```

It's not a big deal, just an opinion to make it better. Forgive me if this does not answer your main question.